# In dart, split string into two parts using length of first string

Tags: dart

I have a string **hiWorld** and
i want to split this string in two parts **hi** and **World** by length of first word **hi** which is of length 2.

This is what i want to do

```dart
List<String> list = ("hiWorld").splitFromLength(2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use the solution you published shortening up the definition:

```dart
List<String> splitStringByLength(String str, int length) =>
    [str.substring(0, length), str.substring(length)];
```

or using an extension method to call the function:

```
extension on String {
  List<String> splitByLength(int length) =>
      [substring(0, length), substring(length)];
}

'helloWorld'.splitByLength(5); // Returns [hello, World].
```

Answer (score 3):

My current solution

```dart
    List<String> splitStringByLength( String str, int length)
    {
        List<String> data = [];

        data.add( str.substring(0, length) );
        data.add( str.substring( length) );
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution which is more generic:

```
List<String> splitByLength(String value, int length) {
  List<String> pieces = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i += length) {
    int offset = i + length;
    pieces.add(value.substring(i, offset >= value.length ? value.length : offset));
  }
  return pieces;
}
```

And the extension method:

```
extension on String {
  List<String> splitByLength(int length, {bool ignoreEmpty = false}) {
    List<String> pieces = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i += length) {
      int offset = i + length;
      String piece = this.substring(i, offset >= this.length ? this.length : offset);
      
      if (ignoreEmpty) {
        piece = piece.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\s+'), '');
      }

      pieces.add(piece);
    }
    return pieces;
  }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
'HELLO WORLD'.splitByLength(5, ignoreEmpty: true)
```